# bxslider shows arrows when not needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, bxslider

I have a html element, that when clicked, it will show my bxSlider. It works good most of the time, however every now and then it shows an arrow when it shouldnt. It happens when there are less than or equal to 3 slides (maxSlides is 3). When the arrow is clicked and nothing is there, the arrow goes away as it should, but it shouldnt of even showed up. I've haven't seen it show both arrows when not needed just one, usually its the right, but sometimes for whatever reason it will show the left one even though there is only 1 item. Its wierd, I can't figure out what its doing as its intermittant.

Here is my JS for bxSlider (using jQuery).

```
$('.specialty ul').bxSlider({
pager: false,
infiniteLoop:false,
hideControlOnEnd:true,
slideWidth: 200,
prevText: '&larr;',
nextText: '&rarr;',
minSlides: 1,
maxSlides: 3,
slideMargin: 0,//10
onSliderLoad: function(){
    $('.bx-wrapper').hide(0);//hide it until a user clicks on something to show it
    info_hidden = true;
}
});
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML code bxSlider uses to create the slides, and maybe some related CSS. I've dealed a lot with bxSlider, but I need to see more.

Comment: Ok, here is the HTML, JS and CSS, I put it in pastebin, hope that helps. THe other thing is that the code uses fancybox to put the slider in, which maybe causing the problem http://pastebin.com/gYa6inbJ

Comment: what does this have to do with fancybox?